# In Infinity War, what is the fighting technique used by Thanos during the fight with the Hulk?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, thanos

In the beginning of "*Avengers: Infinity War*", Thanos and the Hulk had a very intense fight:

While the Hulk fights like he's brawling in the street, Thanos is more composed and posing in stances like in most martial arts, so he seems to be using a specific fighting technique. Moreover, his style looks like something between boxing and/or krav maga, but the fight ends quickly so unfortunately we only see a few of Thanos' moves, as

> he easily beats the crap out of the Hulk.

So my question is: **What is exactly Thanos' fighting technique?**

In-Universe info would be preferable, but out-of-Universe would be also ok if the former is not available.

Comment: Winning? He fights to win, that's his style.

Comment: What kind of answer, exactly, are you expecting?

Comment: @Edlothiad The specific style/technique Thanos used. I think it's a specific question with a specific answer.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe there's a specific technique he used?

Comment: As mentioned in the question, Thanos seems composed and posing in stances like in most martial arts, so I was wondering if he's using a specific technique/martial art.

Comment: Is the answer your looking for some kind of an in-universe titanese art or the real world martial art styles to coregraphy is based on. (also love that "spoiler")

Comment: @Ummdustry Preferably in-Universe, but out-of-Universe would be ok if info on the former is not available.

Comment: Looked like [Vaapad](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Form_VII) to me.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Wrong franchise :P

Comment: The specific technique is "I'm Faster, Smarter, and Kicking Your Ass".

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cXsW5ydr-Ek for another breakdown that points out MMA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a direct answer of a style, but [this breakdown](https://mobile.twitter.com/robinblackmma/status/1030136466826059778?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1030136466826059778&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2Frobinblackmma%2Fstatus%2F1030136466826059778) doesn't note anything exotic in the movements, pointing out that it's generic, if well choreographed, upright striking like you might see in an MMA bout, almost all hands until the head grab into the knee strike.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cXsW5ydr-Ek backs this up, pointing out specific techniques. The main exception is that Ramsey points out that Thanos peels Hulks arms off of him from the outside when from the inside was the mechanically superior option. Here, Thanos acts as he does simply to show superior strength.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it to be judo.
He seems to understand judo, judging by how he uses Hulk's weight against him, and seeing as how he uses a lot of grappling while fighting, such as when he fights Tony on Titan.

Comment: Interesting guess, but I doubt Thanos would know judo, so do you have any references/quotes to support this? That would greatly improve your answer.

Comment: @Rebel-Scum As a martial artist, I would bid you to take "Judo" rather as a label for "an effective grappling art". Due to physical and biomechanical constraints, there are only so many ways to effectively grapple and people all around the world ended up with more or less the same wrestling techniques, because these are the ones that work. The gist of the answer is that he used *grappling* against a heavy, strong opponent to dominate him instead of *striking*, which makes a lot of sense. (19 years on the mats here)

Comment: Seeing as how I'm less than fifteen, I think it was an alright answer.

Comment: Not that I'm trying to be snarky.

Comment: Also, there isn't really a limit to grappling. If you have a different tool, such as a hook or chain, there are hundreds more possibilities.

Comment: If you think that using a hook or a chain to trip up or grab at an opponent counts, that is.